# Inheriting Silverlight 3 control does not initialize content

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a silverlight custom control named "BASE".  I have another control that inherits from this class, "CHILD1".  BASE has a ContentPresenter that holds the content from the CHILD1 control.  I need to access a TextBox that is in the content of the CHILD1 control, it initiailzes, and displays, but it is always null in the code.

Is there a way to access these controls directly instead of iterating over the children collection of the content property?

Thanks.

CHILD1:

```
<local:BASE x:Class="CWTest1.CHILD1"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CWTest"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           Width="400"
           Height="300">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot2"
      Background="White">
    <TextBox x:Name="tbx1"
             Text="xx" />
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class CHILD1 : BASE
{
    public CHILD1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // this.tbx1 is always null
        this.tbx1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Part of BASE:

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                      x:Name="cprContent"
                      Content="" />
```

Base class code:-

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public partial class cwBase1 : ChildWindow
...
new public object Content
    {
        get { return cprContent.Content; }
        set { cprContent.Content = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Not enough detail about BASE what does it derive from?  Is it a `ContentControl` or a plain `Control`?

Comment: it derives from "ChildWindow" 

[ContentProperty("Content")] 
public partial class cwBase1 : ChildWindow 
... 
new public object Content { 
get { return cprContent.Content; } 
set { cprContent.Content = value; } }

Comment: sorry about the lack of formatting, I cannot seem to get linebreaks in a comment.

Comment: @sako73:  That is because you should put code in your question not in a comment.  See the edit link under the question?

Answer (score 0):

Is the TextBox still null if you tried to focus it in the OnApplyTemplate override instead of the constructor?

```
public partial class CHILD1 : BASE
{
    public CHILD1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.tbx1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it should be this difficult, but here is the work around that I got to work:

```
[ContentProperty("Content2")]
public partial class cwBase1 : ChildWindow
{
    ....
    public object Content2
    {
        get { return cprContent.Content; }
        set { cprContent.Content = value; }
    }
    ....
    protected T GetUIElement<T>(string name)
    {
        UIElement el = ((Grid)this.Content2).Children.FirstOrDefault(ui => 
            ui.GetType() == typeof(T) && 
            ui.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(ui, null).ToString() == name);

        return (T)(object)el;
    }
}




public partial class inherit2 : cwBase1
{
    public inherit2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetUIElement<TextBox>("tbx1").Focus();
    }
}
```

I am still very interested in hearing what the technically correct solution is.